# JMS like queue implementation using Scala

Tags: java, scala, jms, akka

Is it possible to implement a JMS message queue in Scala using the Akka framework?

Comment: Scala, not SCALA.  No need to shout.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it from [here](http://krasserm.blogspot.com/2010/04/akka-features-for-application.html):

> Since version 0.7, Akka offers a new
>   feature that let actors send and
>   receive messages over a great variety
>   of protocols and APIs. In addition to
>   the native Scala actor API, actors can
>   now exchange messages with other
>   systems over large number of protcols
>   and APIs such as HTTP, SOAP, TCP, FTP,
>   SMTP or **JMS**, to mention a few. At the
>   moment, approximately 80 protocols and
>   APIs are supported. This new feature
>   is provided by Akka's Camel module.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, presumably. All you'd need is the ability to support the JMS interfaces, and since Scala can implement Java interfaces and extend Java classes...